# Apex Test Class and Trigger Help

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I am trying to write a trigger that will not allow an account with an opportunity to be deleted. The test says I have 60% coverage and i'm not covering the bottom part of my trigger handler.

This is what I have:

Trigger Handler:

```java
Public Class ContactTriggerHandler {
    public static void addError (List<Contact> oldContacts) {
        for (Contact a : [SELECT Id FROM Contact
                          WHERE Id IN (SELECT ContactId FROM Opportunity) AND
                     Id IN :Trigger.old]) {

            /*test says below is not covered*/
            Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id).addError(
            'Cannot delete friend with opportunity.');   
        }
    }
}
```

TEST:

```java
@isTest
public class ContactTriggerHandler_Test {
    @isTest
    private static void testErrorMethod () {
        Contact con = new Contact(LastName='Test');
        insert con;
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test', CloseDate = date.newInstance(2024, 9, 21), Conact__c = con.Id , StageName ='' );
        insert opp;
        Test.startTest();
        database.deleteResult result = database.delete(con, false);
        test.stopTest();

        Con = [SELECT LastName FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'Test'];
        System.Assert(Result.isSuccess());
        System.Assert(Result.getErrors().size() > 0);
        System.AssertEquals('Cannot delete friend with opportunity.', Result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the main issue here is that you're not setting up your test data correctly.

The class/method that you're testing has
`WHERE Id IN (SELECT ContactId FROM Opportunity)`

and your test setup is
`new Opportunity(..., Conact__c = con.Id);`

Potential typo on `Conact__c` aside, the `Contact__c` field is not the same as the `ContactId` field.

So you need to set `ContactId` on your test `Opportunity`, to match the `ContactId` field you're using in your semi-join in the method you're trying to test. Without that, your query is going to return 0 rows, and that's going to cause you to not execute the code inside your for loop (which explains why you aren't getting coverage).

Beyond that, I have two recommendations:

1. I'd consider using a query like `SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :Trigger.old AND Id IN (SELECT ContactId FROM Opportunity WHERE ContactId IN :Trigger.old)`. The hope here is that Salesforce would be able to come up with a better execution plan (that doesn't involve it working over *all* of your Opportunities). There's likely no observable difference in performance, but it could prevent you from running into issues later on (when your org has hundreds of thousands of Opportunities)
2. While you do need *some* coverage for the trigger itself, your test should generally be calling `ContactTriggerHandler.addError()` directly. This makes your test class more focused/isolated, which usually means tests will be easier to write (and errors easier to track down).

Comment: re: 1. where do i insert that line? is it where I currently have the con =?

Comment: @ArtimusFowl No, that's a replacement for the query that you have in `ContactTriggerHandler.addError()`.